# Peer-to-peer networking using USB 3.0

Tags: usb, p2p

Has anyone tried USB 3.0 based peer-to-peer networking?

1. I tried connecting my PC and laptop via the USB 3.0. Neither of the
   them were able to detect the other.
2. Check the USB driver update -  the check indicates the driver is the latest

   [image: Picture-1: USB driver snapshot]
3. As per the USB 3.0 host-to-host communication should be supported. I understand that is what is meant by 'crossover connection' in http://blog.ironkey.com/the-4-benefits-of-usb-3-0-are-you-ready-for-this/
4. Preferably - Windows 7, Windows embedded related experiment results would be interesting to hear about :)

Comment: Are you looking for IP over USB? It's still a feature that needs to be explicitly supported by the OS (much like the existing USB On-the-Go), not something that automagically happens when the ports are compatible... (I remember IPv4 over Firewire was supported in WinXP but removed in Win7.)

Comment: I'd ask why? 1Gb eth links will provide you with 120MB/s effective rate, unless you're pushing huge files which is unlikely with a laptop its realy not worth the hassle.

Comment: @grawity - I'm not looking at IP over USB.

Comment: @linef4ult - because I want to use the 5Gbps transfer speed that USB 3.0 offers

Comment: Are both machines using large SSDs? @Keshavan

Comment: @Linef4ult: Currently no. I've ordered for machines with SSD - expect to get it shortly

Comment: @Keshavan: What "networking", precisely, are you looking for then?

Comment: As long as I'm able to transfer in excess of 50MB/s I'm not restrained in choosing the type of networking. This transfer will continue through the active operation of my application

Answer (score -1):

As you can get from this discussion

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.usb.general/58432

technically host-to-host communication is possible BUT:

- nearly no host has the optional components for this

and

- therefore the OS support is scarce.

Comment: Shame that link doesn't work any more :-(